# How to create a chart sheet with a column chart from a button on a form and data on a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is part of my final project for an Excel VBA class. I have created a calculator app that also writes the equations and results to the *MathResults* sheet. My next task is to take the results and create a chart sheet with them. The issue I am getting from the code below is that the subscript is out of range *Set ws = Sheets("MathResults")*. This code worked fine when I used it to select the worksheet to write the data to.

```
Private Sub bttnAddChart_Click()
    'variables
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim endRow As Integer
    Set ws = Sheets("MathResults")

    'find the end of the row
    endRow = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:="", After:=Range("A1")).Row

    'set the data range
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("B2:B" & endRow)

    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .Legend.Position = xlRight
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinorTickMark = xlOutside
        .Axes(xlValue).MinorTickMark = xlOutside
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your Workbook does not have a sheet called `"MathResults"`. What you want is to **create it** then work with it.

Change

> `Set ws = Sheets("MathResults")`

into:

```
Set ws = Sheets.Add
ws.Name = "MathResults"
```

Better yet, you can try to find the sheet and create it IF it is not yet there:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets("MathResults")
If ws Is Nothing Then ' <~~ the sheet is not there yet, we need to create it
    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "MathResults"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: It does have a sheet named MathResults, as I stated above I have already written data to the sheet and selected the sheet with the same code that caused a problem here.

Comment: @codingYogi If the sheet `MathResults` already exists, then the only thing I could think of is that the Workbook containing it might not be the active one. Do you have more than workbook open at the time you invoke this routine?

Comment: You were right, I had more than one workbook open Thanks! For some reason though when I run the code now it adds the chart sheet but freezes excel on a blank chart. Can you think of any reason this would be happening?

Comment: @codingYogi Glad it helped. I think that this now you are facing a different issue. If you did not solve it yet, I suggest that you post a dedicated question.

Comment: Thanks but it only lets me ask one question every 4 days, very annoying.

Comment: It might be again the result of counting on which wb is Active, which worksheet is active, etc. I highly recommend to use fully qualified objects, where each statement specifies precisely the object (wb, ws, chart, etc) it applies to, instead of the `ActiveThing`... For example `With someWorkbook.Charts.Add`...